# How to edit and update <td> value when double click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written my code such that when user double clicks on a `<td>` element I am:

- appending am `<input>` of `type="text"`
- adding a value to it and update it if the user clicks on enter

**Here is the my problem:**

If user double clicks on `<td>` and clicks on another `<td>` without pressing enter, I need the initial `<td>`'s `<input>` to be reset to previous value.

```
// Selecting the table <th> odd elements
$("#div table td").dblclick(function(){
    var currentEle = $(this);
    var value = $(this).html();
    updateVal(currentEle, value);
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value)
{
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="'+value+'" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $('body').not(".thVal").click(function(){
        if(('.thVal').length != 0)
        {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me.
I don't want to use jeditable datatable.

Comment: please take a look at this : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Editable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202723/how-to-edit-data-onclick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here in your case you need `.stopPropagation()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jFycy/

```
$(function () {
    $("#div table td").dblclick(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();      //<-------stop the bubbling of the event here
       var currentEle = $(this);
       var value = $(this).html();
       updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
  $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
  $(".thVal").focus();
  $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
      }
  });

  $(document).click(function () { // you can use $('html')
        $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
  });
}
```

Instead doing click on `body` do the event on `document` or `html` which is the parent elem of all others elems.

Comment: Justo to mantion if you click more thant ones of a field to edit it you should remove the `click` event with $(document).off('click') because there are some issues comming from that.
fiddle->http://jsfiddle.net/melanholly/D9YS3/

Comment: there is problem in this code. if you double click within Input field to select the content, it will trigger the TD's double click and close the box/reset the box.

Comment: @SumitGupta If you add this
`
$('.inner').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
`
Just before the document.click -- The problem will be solved

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the last answer. by checking who triggered the event i can prevent the double click issue on the input.

Also, with the .off('click') you dont have the problem where every td you updated before changes with the last one.

```
$(function () {
    $(".inner").dblclick(function (e) {
        if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal")
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var currentEle = $(this);
                var value = $(this).html();
                updateVal(currentEle, value);
        }
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(document).off('click');
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {

            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {

            if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal")
            {
                $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
                $(document).off('click');
            }

    });

}
```

Comment: Should not `event.target` be `e.target`?

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old topic... but the answer that posted here didnt worked well because of the click event on the input, I took the answer and modified it

```
$(".daily-signals > tbody > tr > td").dblclick(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();      //<-------stop the bubbling of the event here
    var currentEle = $(this);
    var value = $(this).html();
    console.log('fire!');
    updateVal(currentEle, value);
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');
    var thVal = $(".thVal");
    thVal.focus();
    thVal.keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html(thVal.val());
            save(thVal.val());
        }
    });

    thVal.focusout(function () {
        $(currentEle).html(thVal.val().trim());
        return save(thVal.val()); // <---- Added missing semi-colon
    });

}

function save(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

the save function will make the ajax request