# Allow editing of Text dynamic php table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have a html table that is generated VIA PHP and data in a database, what I want to do is have a button in the last cell of each row that says edit and when you click that button the text in the other cells becomes textboxes or other types of input fields so that you can edit them and then press submit which would send that form off to be updated in the database. The code I have right now to generate the table is:

```
<table style="width:100%; " class = "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Description</th>
     <?php 
        if($_SESSION['editGroup'] != 0){
           echo "<th>Edit</th>";
        }
     ?>
  </tr>
 <?php
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $checkQuery = "SELECT userGiven, userStatus, userDesc FROM user_Status WHERE organization = 'myOrg' ORDER BY userGiven ASC";
    $prepared = $dbh->prepare($checkQuery);
    $prepared->execute();
    $data = $prepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($data as $row){
      echo "<tr>";
      if($_SESSION['editGroup'] != 0){
      echo "<td width='20%'>" . $row['userGiven'] . "</td><td width='10%'>" . $row['userStatus'] . "</td><td width='70%'>" . $row['userDesc'] . "</td><td width='10%'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</button></td>";
      }else{
         echo "<td width='20%'>" . $row['userGiven'] . "</td><td width='15%'>" . $row['userStatus'] . "</td><td width='75%'>" . $row['userDesc'] . "</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";             
    }
 ?>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is change the cell with userStatus to a drop down field with the current value as the starting value and the other value in/out as the other value to select between.

I also want to change the userDesc to a textarea and I think I know how to do all this but I am running into a problem conceptually when I try to apply it to the dynamic table.

What I was thinking was that I could use jquery/javascript to get the innerhtml of span variable that could surround those two cells and then change the html to the various input fields containing the current text allowing the user editing them to change those values.

How do I do this for this sort of problem though, I would need onClick events for all the buttons and I wouldn't know how many buttons there would be, that's based off of the number of rows in the table.

That would result in hundreds of lines of redundant code so I assume there has to be a much better way. Anyone know what a way to accomplish this? I found this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202723/how-to-edit-data-onclick` which is close to what I want but that seems to be static values where I want to be able to do this for any of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you'll want to put something identifiable in the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements. I'd personally go with a data-attribute. For example:

**Echo Row Code**

```
foreach($data as $row){
  echo "<tr data-row='{$row[id]}'>";
  if($_SESSION['editGroup'] != 0){
     echo "<td width='20%' data-column='name'>" . $row['userGiven'] . "</td><td width='10%' data-column='status'>" . $row['userStatus'] . "</td><td width='70%' data-column='description'>" . $row['userDesc'] . "</td><td width='10%'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</button></td>";
  }else{
     echo "<td width='20%'>" . $row['userGiven'] . "</td><td width='15%'>" . $row['userStatus'] . "</td><td width='75%'>" . $row['userDesc'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";             
}
```

So, as you can see I've added a `data-row` attribute to `<tr>` which should get the value of the database record's ID. Change it as necessary - I made the assumption it'd be named 'id'. Also, I added the `data-column` attribute to `<td>` which should identify each column for us. This is all the modification needed in the PHP.

Now, here's what the JQuery for the edit button looks like:

**Front-End Event Listener: Part 1**

```
$( function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".btn-info", function(){

        var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = $(parent).attr("data-row");
        var name = $(parent).children("[data-column='name']");
        var status = $(parent).children("[data-column='status']");
        var desc = $(parent).children("[data-column='description']");
        var nameTxt = $(name).html();
        var statusTxt = $(status).html();
        var descTxt = $(desc).html();

        $(name).html("<input name='name' data-dc='name' value='" + nameTxt + "'>");
        $(status).html("<input name='status' data-dc='status' value='" + statusTxt + "'>");
        $(desc).html("<textarea name='desc' data-dc='description'>" + descTxt + "</textarea>");

        $(this).replaceWith("<button class='btn-info-save'>Save</button>");
    });

}
```

Finally, we need to define what happens upon hitting save (the above example changes the "edit" button into a "save" button). That could be anything, but we'll assume it'll be an AJAX call:

**Front-End Event Listener: Part 2**

```
$( function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".btn-info-save", function(){

        var parent = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = $(parent).attr("data-row");
        var data = {id: id};

        $("[data-dc]").each( function(){
            var col = $(this).attr("data-dc");
            var val = $(this).val();

            data[col] = val;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/dynamic-edit/edit.php", // Change this to your PHP update script!
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(ret){
                //Do Something
                console.log(ret.response);
               },
            error: function(ret){
                console.log(ret.response);
               }
        });

    });

}
```

Now, in your PHP script that handles the AJAX request:

**PHP Code for 'edit.php'**

```
$name = $_POST['data_name'];
$status = $_POST['data_status'];
$description = $_POST['data_description'];

// Do whatever with the data

// Output JSON - get the response in JS with ret.response
// either inside the success or error portion of the AJAX
echo json_encode( ["response"=>"Row edited successfully."] );
```

This is a very simple example, but it gets the point across. Be sure to change the AJAX url from "/dynamic-edit/edit.php" to wherever you'll make your PHP script that will actually make the updates after submitting.

You'll likely want to do cleanup after a successful edit; for example, changing the text boxes back to just text in a `<td>`. Also, please note that I just changed them to textboxes. I know you said in your post you wanted to make one the status a dropdown and the description a textarea, but this example should be easy enough to change. I don't know what the values of the dropdown should be, so you'll have to do that part.

**Notes**

I went with `$(document).on("click" ...` instead of `$(".btn-info").on("click" ...` because whenever you're dealing with dynamic content, you always want the event listener on the document, not the element. Why? Because if you click the "edit" button, it disappears and a "save" button appears, you now lose that event listener forever. If you were to re-add the "edit" button (say, after a successful save), that button would need the event listener added again. When you go the route of attaching the event listener to the *document*, however, you can remove/add all you want and it'll still work.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what is going on and I think I can definetly work through any small errors I encounter, thanks for all that, I found some tutorial that sort of went off this approach but they all cost money and were way more  than what I wanted, I was really hoping to get this working instead of having to use popup modals.

Comment: Any time! I agree, inline editing seems to be more elegant than a modal (though modals are cool for specific uses). Hopefully it all works out - let me know if you run into any snags!

Comment: The only small snag I am having right now is var parent = $(this).nearest("tr"); where .nearest(...) is not a function, is there a library I have to include or a file? I can probably figure out a way to get it to grab that tr since it has the ID attached to it.

Comment: Nate, if you still check this, I am having trouble with the .val() for fields in the AJAX part, I am sending blank data over because all 3 .val() are equal to nothing, the data looks like data_name: (blank); data_status: (blank); data_description: (blank); I have tried as many methods as I could think of to correct the problem but I am still not getting any values to be passed.

Comment: Hey @AndyPet74, let me take a look at it and debug it a bit. I bet I have a typo there somewhere.

Comment: @AndyPet74 I had some errors - sorry about that. Check the code now, what I posted has been tested and is functional :)

Comment: @AndyPet74 Oh, forgot to mention, I updated all the code examples except the first PHP example. Be sure to update them on your end.

Comment: thank you very much, I wasn't expecting someone to write out a working solutions like this. Thanks, it is sending data correctly to my edit page and seems to be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'data' attribute to each button with the user id that you want to update. For example:

```
<button data-iduser='<?= $use["id"] ?>' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</button>

$("btn btn-info").click( function() {
   var idUser = $(this).attr("data-iduser");
   // some ajax if you want with that iD
});
```

Comment: so the <? = $use["id"] would I replace that with something like <? = $row["id"] ?> are you just using the $use variable as a way to show me where I would set it equal to the ID I want it to be equal to. Also why is it data-iduser=' <? = as in why is there 2 equal signs?

Comment: <?= ?> it's like <?php echo ?>. In your own code you should write <button data-iduser='{$use["id"]}' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</button>

Comment: my $use["id"] would be something different though right? It would be whatever variable I am storing the ID in correct?

Comment: Yes sorry, it was an example. You should use the var where user id is store. I suppose that in your case should be something like '$row["id"]' ?

Comment: Alright, that is what I was doing so I was just double checking. Currently I am trying to get the var idUser to get the value of that new attribute that was made on the button. I inserted an alert(idUser); right after that variable is created to show me what the value of it is but right now it is returning undefined but the button does have the id stored in the attribute data-iduser which is a plus. EDIT: I got that part figured out, I am now working with ajax to change those columns to proper fields so that I can edit them.

Comment: It has wrong syntax, try this: var idUser = $(this).attr("data-iduser");